# Android Studio Error : Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError:

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Could not delete caches dir C:\Users~~~\app\build\kotlin\kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin

The above problem causing in android studio while using the Android Studio.
When I delete this /build folder and run the application again then it's working fine but after 5 to 10 minutes the same problem occurs again and again.

Windows OS : Windows 10 Pro,  2.42 GHz i5

Android Studio : 2020.3.1 Patch 4

Already Tried Methods:

1 - By running the studio as Administrator - Not working

2 - By closing the java.exe process for Task Manager - Not working

Comment: Problem not occurred again after installing latest JDK requested by Android Studio updater